# RxJS5 Mongo issue

Tags: mongodb, rxjs, rxjs5

I have some RxJS code using mongo to perform queries. Works fine in RxJS v4 but as I am migrating to v.5 I am running into issues.

Here's some simplified code:

```
// Get a mongo connection
getDb() {
  var connect = Rx.Observable.bindNodeCallback(mongodb.connect)
  return connect(this.options.connection.uri, this.options.connection.options)
}

// Query
return getDb()
  .flatMap((db) => {
    var c = db.collection('foo')
    var obs = Rx.Observable.bindNodeCallback(c.insertMany, c)
    return obs(docs)
  })
  .subscribe(...)
```

Every time I try some sort of query it fails with various errors. All the errors are related to an `options` object not existing inside the Mongo code. I think this may be a context issue but I am not sure.

The query above yields (in the code, undefined is a mongo collection options object)

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'serializeFunctions' of undefined
at BoundNodeCallbackObservable.Collection.insertMany[as callbackFunc](node_modules / mongodb / lib / collection.js: 482: 74)
```

A similar query yields:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'options' of undefined
at BoundNodeCallbackObservable.Collection.remove[as callbackFunc](node_modules / mongodb / lib / collection.js: 1223: 12)
```

**Update** When I wrap it manually things work:

```
var obs = Rx.Observable.create(function(observer) {
   c.insertMany(docs, function(err, res) {
     if (err) { observer.error(err) } else {
       observer.next(res);
       observer.complet();
      }
    })
  })
  return obs

 // This doesn't:
 var obs = Rx.Observable.bindNodeCallback(c.insertMany, c)
 return obs(docs)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok. Turns out `bindNodeCallback` and `bindCallback` do not allow for context to be passed. So we need to do this:

```
c.insertMany = c.insertMany.bind(c)
var obs = Rx.Observable.bindNodeCallback(c.insertMany)
```

Comment: This saved me a huge headache. I figured it hand to do with the lexical scoping of 'this' in my code.

Comment: I encountered the same problem with ftp, I just specified
`
    Rx.Observable(c.ready.bind(c))
`
without changing original object, that may be not wanted, or it does not really care, but it works and is ok